# remove margin/indent in my adsense div

Tags: css, adsense

i want to put google adsense 728x90 text ads in my single post page.
the problem is why the ads seems like indent itself? how to remove the margin on the left? (refer attachment)

i already set the div for my ad margin:0; padding:0; but still nothing happen

[image]

Comment: try using firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) to select the elements in question - you can then learn where the style is being set and replicate the path to overwrite it

Comment: Or if you're in Chrome, right click an element, and click Inspect Element. In in IE, press F12.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a new rule but that heading above the ad saying "FAVORITE ..." (presumably "FAVORITE SITES") is strictly against Adsense policies nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ads are using unordered list() to display them. Use firebug to identify what it is. If so then use CSS selector #adDiv ul{padding:0; margin:0;}; where #adDiv is the id of DIV where you put your ad. You can use class also.

Answer (score 0):

The ads are indeed indented slightly. I would not, however, attempt to change their indenting in any way, as it could be viewed as contravening the AdSense terms and conditions.

What I usually do is adjust the padding of my content to line up with the ads. Much simpler solution.